# remove unwanted ' \' from json values with html tags , generated using amazonaws json toolkit

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services

I use amazonaws library[com.amazonaws.util.json] (java)  for generate json .
  I use something as follows

```
    private static final String boldHtmlOpenTag = "<b>";
private static final String boldHtmlCloseTag = "</b>";
private static final String italicsHtmlOpenTag = "<i>";
private static final String italicsHtmlCloseTag = "</i>";
    String result = boldHtmlOpenTag + "hello" + boldHtmlCloseTag;
    jsonobj.put("test",result);
```

I get the response as `{"test" : <b> hello<\/b>}`.
 I need output as without the `\`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to include html tags in json, But at the closing tags I got an escape slash may be added by the json library.

Comment: I'm asking about the code you posted on the question, because it isn't java right?

Comment: @Francisco Spaeth I use java code and amazonaws eclipse toolkit

Comment: I asked because it isn't a valid Java code, `string` isn't a known type, and if you don't add the `;` at the end of the line you will not finish the sentence.

Comment: @Francisco Spaeth its only sample

Comment: I see, maybe the answer I gave could help you then.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, why not just do

```
result = result.replace("\\","");
```

**EDIT:**
Okay, then why not do this:

```
boldHtmlCloseTag = "<&frasl;b>";
```

That should still be legal JSON.

Comment: The problem is my genaerated json value is a string with htmltags inside it.At the closing part the amazon lib put an extra backslash

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't seems there. I suppose the value containing the tags you load from somewhere else, and there the value is stored with this escape char.

I conclude this because:

1. the sample given is not java, what makes me feel that you just wrote a pseudo sample for this issue;
2. the amazon json API doesn't comment anything about escape chars, and implementation is according API (I checked it).

So, please check from where you get the information and if there isn't stored with the wrong value.

Comment: I tried a small set of code in main function , I got the same result

Comment: import com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONException;
import com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject;
    final String boldHtmlOpenTag = "<b>";
    final String boldHtmlCloseTag = "</b>";
    final String italicsHtmlOpenTag = "<i>";
    final String italicsHtmlCloseTag = "</i>";
    String str = boldHtmlOpenTag + italicsHtmlOpenTag
      + "Hello" + italicsHtmlOpenTag
      + boldHtmlCloseTag;
    String str1 ="<b>"+"hello"+"</b>";
  JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
  jsonobj.put("test", str1);
  System.out.println(jsonobj.toString());

Comment: Yea, i test it as a java applicaion

Answer (score 0):

Try this one !

```
result = result.replace("\\\\","");
```